# trying to create 10 bit image Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a 10 bit per channel fake black image.
Where all of the channels equals 16.
 
Here is what I have tried

```
image = zeros(100,100);
image(:,:) = 16;
fileID = fopen('blc.raw','w');
fwrite(fileID,image,'double');
```

Can you please tell me how to create a 10 bit image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB does not have a 10 bit data type, so you can not have 10 bit images. However, you can have 16 bit images and cap the topmost value to `2^10-1`.

you can create a 16bit image doing `img=uint16(ones(100,100)*16);`

Generally you'd want to write images using `imwrite`.

Comment: I'm  trying to get headerless raw image, not a tiff/jpg... so this is why i'm not using imwrite

Comment: @Gilad still, in `fwrite` precision, you can see that there is no a 10bit option, as there is no a 10 bit data type in Matlab.

Comment: Thanks. I will use what you wrote